# How to get additional attribute of enum value?

Tags: java, enums

In my chat application I have an enum:

```
enum ContactRelationType {
  Friend,
  Familiar,
  Ignored,
  Unknown,  
  Guild,
  Officers,
  Academy,
  Community,
  System
}
```

Half of ContactRelationType values are rooms (Guild, Officers, Academy,  Community, System).
I need to know is the value room or not.

I know three ways to do it:

The first:

```
enum ContactRelationType {
  Friend,
  Familiar,
  Ignored,
  Unknown,  
  Guild,
  Officers,
  Academy,
  Community,
  System;

    public boolean isRoom() {
    return this == Guild ||
        this == Officers ||
        this == Academy ||
        this == Community ||
        this == System;
  }
}
```

It looks ugly and the IDEA tells me "Overly complex boolean expression" and it is.

The second:

```
    enum ContactRelationType {
      Friend,
      Familiar,
      Ignored,
      Unknown,  
      Guild,
      Officers,
      Academy,
      Community,
      System;

    public boolean isRoom() {
      switch (this) {
        case Guild:
        case Officers:
        case Academy:
        case Community:
        case System:
          return true;
        default:
          return false;
    }
}
```

it looks ugly too.

The third:

```
    public enum ContactRelationType {
      Friend(false),
      Familiar(false),
      Ignored(false),
      Unknown(false),
      Guild(true),
      Officers(true),
      Academy(true),
      Community(true),
      System(true);

      private boolean room;

      ContactRelationType(boolean room) {
        this.room = room;
      }

      public boolean isRoom() {
        return room;
      }
}
```

But in this case I have `boolean room` in all enum instances.

So, what solution is better and why?

Comment: `private static final Set<ContactRelationType> ROOMS = EnumSet.range(Guild, System)`. Then in the method `ROOMS.contains(this)`. The more pertinent question is why is your `enum` representing two distinct types?

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a good solution. I would not like to distinct this types in UI.

Comment: Third is the most elegant, fit to Java best practices etc (books from Joshua Blosh etc). Don't be afraid with few bytes of data (and maybe less bytes of code?)

Comment: How does the internal representation of data affect the UI in any way? Something is very wrong here...

Comment: Designer point of view: constant list of Rooms is ok in student projects, but seems bad in real-life. Every requirements to extend list need code intervention

Comment: If the UI does not distinguish, make a union there. Probably let the two enum types implement a common interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably could use an `EnumSet`. They are very efficiently implemented with a `BitSet` equivalent.

```
enum ContactRelationType {

    Friend,
    Familiar,
    Ignored,
    Unknown,
    Guild,
    Officers,
    Academy,
    Community,
    System;

    public boolean isRoomRelation() {
        return RoomContacts.contains(this);
    }
}

static final Set<ContactRelationType> RoomContacts = EnumSet.of(
        ContactRelationType.Guild,
        ContactRelationType.Officers,
        ContactRelationType.Academy,
        ContactRelationType.Community,
        ContactRelationType.System);
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider - That may be more efficient but assumes something not stated.

Answer (score 5):

You solution with boolean flag is good. Just add a default constructor:

```
 ContactRelationType() {
    this(false);
  }
```

Now you do not have to write `true` or `false` for each enum member; only for those that are not "default":

```
public enum ContactRelationType {
  Friend,
  Familiar,
  Ignored,
  Unknown,
  Guild(true),
  Officers(true),
  Academy(true),
  Community(true),
  System(true);
```